# Can someone please explain to me what the java code here is doing?

Tags: java

I am learning java using the headfirst Java book. I have a problem understanding what some Java do and how an output came to be. For example:

```
class MultiFor {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        int x = 0;
        int y = 30;

        for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer++){
            for (int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--){
                x = x + 3;
                y = y - 2;
                if (x == 6){
                    break;
                }
                x = x + 3;
            }
            y = y - 2;
        }
        System.out.println(x + " "  + y);
    }
}
```

my output is 54 6, but i don't know how it came to be. Can someone explain this?

Comment: pretty good time to start using the debug functions on your IDE....

Comment: It's difficult to describe exactly what it's doing, but in a nutshell it's adding and subtracting from x and y several times before printing the results.  Which bit are you confused by exactly?

Comment: @stevesmith the adding and subtracting part.How the for loop works in this case .

Comment: the loops are only there to execute a specific number of time the increment/decrement, there is no link between [x,y] and [outer, inner]. So the only interesting part is the `break`.

Comment: "for-loops" are a very basic programming construct.  I would look at a simple Java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The For-Loops works that way:

for(initialisation ; condition; steps){
 do Stuff
}

initialisation is the part where Variables are defined not necessary Variables for the condition but they are only reachable in the for-loop.

condition as long as the condition is true the will run again.

steps mostly an interation for the loops in this case its outer = outer +1 and inner = inner -1.

in this example the outer for-loop runs from outer=0  to outer=2 and the inner runs from inner = 4 to inner = 2.
In the If-Condition is tested on x == 6 after reaching this true status it will stop the inner for-loop with a break;.

thats what it do how it reachs the expected values is just counting the loops and adding values.